# Logback similar to JsonTemplateLayout and eventTemplateUri

Tags: spring, logging, log4j2, logback, vert.x

I need to set JSON Object for logging. I have used logback. I was looking on net and seems like log4j2 gives user the capability to do this using

```
<JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:Log4j2EventLayout.json"/>
```

Where Log4j2EventLayout.json is a file where we can define the structure of logging.

I looked online to find if logback gives such capability and i couldn't find it.

However I know we can extend JsonLayout

```
public class CustomLogJsonLayout extends JsonLayout {

  public CustomLogJsonLayout() {
    this.setIncludeMDC(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected void addCustomDataToJsonMap(Map<String, Object> map, ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
    map.putAll(iLoggingEvent.getMDCPropertyMap());
    super.addCustomDataToJsonMap(map, iLoggingEvent);
  }
}
```

and whenever I am doing log.error . I am adding the data in MDC.

```
MDC.put('url', url)
log.error('')
MDC.clear;
```

And I get Json Structure in logs

**Doing this everywhere seems very long process. Do we have something what log4j2 offers.**